# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined Error when using axios.get inside useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

This is my edit-exercises component given below. So in my exercises component when I am clicking
**edit** to update my exercises with respect to its id, it has to render to edit-exercise component
but on rendering it gives above mentioned error. This is my component for the reference. In this, in
useEffect I am fetching my exercise with given id from the URL.

````
    import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
    import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
    import axios from "axios";

    const EditExercise = (props) => {
      const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({
        username: "",
        description: "",
        duration: 0,
        date: new Date(),
        users: [],
      });
    
      useEffect(() => {                         //This is the getting from backend
        axios
         .get("http://localhost:5000/exercises/"+props.match.params.id)
          .then(res => {
            setUserDetails({
              username: res.data.username,
              description: res.data.description,
              duration: res.data.duration,
              date: new Date(res.data.date),
            })
         })        
          .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);        
          });
    
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:5000/users/")
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.data.length > 0) {
              setUserDetails({
                users: res.data.map((user) => user.username),
              });
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
        },[props.match.params.id]);
    
      const changeUsernameHandler = (e) => {
        setUserDetails((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            username: e.target.value,
          };
        });
      };
    
      const changeDescriptionHandler = (e) => {
        setUserDetails((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            description: e.target.value,
          };
        });
      };
    
      const changeDurationHandler = (e) => {
        setUserDetails((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            duration: e.target.value,
          };
        });
      };
    
      const changeDateHandler = (date) => {
        setUserDetails((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            date: date,
          };
        });
      };
    
      const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {                                //On submit this code will run
        e.preventDefault();
        const exercise = {
          username: userDetails.username,
          description: userDetails.description,
          duration: userDetails.duration,
          date: userDetails.date,
        };
        console.log(exercise);
    
        axios
          .post("http://localhost:5000/exercises/update/"+props.match.params.id, exercise)
          .then((res) => console.log(res.data));
    
        window.location = "/";
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>Edit Exercise log</h3>
          <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Username: </label>
              <select
                required
                className="form-control"
                onChange={changeUsernameHandler}
                value={userDetails.username}
              >
                {userDetails.users.map((user) => {
                  return (
                    <option key={user} value={user}>
                      {user}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Description: </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                required
                className="form-control"
                onChange={changeDescriptionHandler}
                value={userDetails.description}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Duration (in minutes): </label>
              <input
                type="number"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={changeDurationHandler}
                value={userDetails.duration}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Date: </label>
              <div>
                <DatePicker
                  onChange={changeDateHandler}
                  selected={userDetails.date}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div>
              <input
                type="submit"
                value="Edit Exercise Log"
                className="btn btn-primary"
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default EditExercise;```


 
>Please suggest what can be done to render the edit-exercise component
````

Comment: Check if your GET from ```"http://localhost:5000/users/"``` actually returns an array response. I suspect ```res.data``` is ```undefined``` an you are calling ```map``` on it

Comment: Yes i am getting an array of users for that

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

This error is thrown because the array you are trying to map doesn't exist.  Please check if the array exists before you map the array.
users: res.data ? res.data.map((user) => user.username) : [],
And

```
{userDetails.users && userDetails.users.map((user) => {
        return (
            <option key={user} value={user}>
                {user}
            </option>
            );
         })}
```

Since `axios.get` returns a promise, and `setUserDetails` is set after the promise is returned, you need to be careful on when `useEffect` is triggered. Currently `useEffect` is triggered when `props.match.params.id` is changed.

There are 2 possible solutions for it:
Either, you can remove `props.match.params.id` from the `useEffect` second parameter.

Or you can this section outside the useEffect hook:

```
axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/users/")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.length > 0) {
          setUserDetails({
            users: res.data.map((user) => user.username),
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: I am getting the data from both exercises and users API endpoint but after commenting the setUserDetails function inside useEffect, my component is getting rendered bt still without changing the state i cannot edit my exercise-list. That is the issue

Comment: Did you try this solution?

Comment: Yes after trying i got the error idea as my username is showing blanked

Comment: Please try those solutions.